# How to pass parameters from portlet to jsp

Tags: jsp, liferay, portlet

I'm trying to pass parameters from a `portlet` to a new jsp. I mean, `view.jsp` is the first page I see when the `portlet` is rendered. This `view.jsp` contains a submit, where an user inserts an ID. That submit invoques a ProcessAction where ID is processed. Once ID has been treated then I need to pass one parameter to a new jsp (not view.jsp). That `newpage.jsp` should be charged after the submit.

How could I do that? I've been searching solutions but I'm getting confused more every day.

**Update:**

Yes, I want to pass parameters from my process action to JSP. But problems persists and I don't know why. I've been reading what your link offers and I've included the lines that the documentation recommends to make it works. But it doesn't work.

Here is my code (action phase):

```
@ProcessAction(name="obtenerExpedientesPorNIF")
public void obtenerExpedientesPorNIF(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {

    //code to process the information I need to pass to the render phase (JSP)

    String[] expedientes_nif = null;
    for (int i=0; i<lista_expedientes.size(); i++)
    {
        ExpedienteListItem expediente = lista_expedientes.get(i);
        expedientes_nif[i] = expediente.getNumeroExpediente();
    }

actionResponse.setRenderParameter("lista-expedientes", expedientes_nif);
}
```

And here is the another one (render phase):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

Insert your ID:<br><br>
<%
String string = renderRequest.getParameter("lista-expedientes");
%>

<portlet:defineObjects />
<portlet:actionURL name="obtenerExpedientesPorNIF" var="addNameUrl">
</portlet:actionURL>
<form action="${addNameUrl}" method="post">
<input name="NIF" type="text"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Realizar búsqueda"/><br>
</form>
```

My IDE reports an error at this line:

```
String string = renderRequest.getParameter("lista-expedientes");
```

So, what changes would you consider my code needs to work?

Answer (score 4):

I understand you want to pass parameters from **Action Phase** to **Render Phase** (so it can be read in by your JSP). It can be done with Render Parameters. First you have to add parameter in you action method:

```
actionResponse.setRenderParameter("parameter-name", "value");
```

and then read id in your render method or JSP file:

```
renderRequest.getParameter("parameter-name");
```

There is an article in [Liferay's documentation](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017871332-Passing-Information-from-the-Action-Phase-to-the-Render-Phase) about passing values to the render phase.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<portlet:defineObjects />` tag before use the `renderRequest` variable:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />

Insert your ID:<br><br>
<%
String string = renderRequest.getParameter("lista-expedientes");
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned below, we can make available the action phase parameters to render phase.

MVCPortlet class to copy all action parameters directly as render parameters. You can achieve this by setting the following init-param in your portlet.xml,

```
XML:
<init-param>
    <name>copy-request-parameters</name>
    <value>true</value>
</init-param>
```